# the java concurrent modification exception debacle of 2010

Tags: java, thread-safety

Painting some particles stored in an ArrayList. This code works fine:

```
 super.paintComponent(g);
             for (Particle b: particleArr){
                  g.setColor(b.getColor());
                  g.fillOval(b.getXCoor() + 5,b.getYCoor(),
                             b.getParticleSize(),b.getParticleSize());
             }
```

However this code throws a concurrent modification exception:

```
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            //paint particles
             super.paintComponent(g);
             for (Particle b: particleArr){
                  g.setColor(b.getColor());
                  if (b.isDead())
                      particleArr.remove(b);
                  else if (!b.isVanishing())
                      g.fillOval(b.getXCoor(),b.getYCoor(),
                            b.getParticleSize(),b.getParticleSize());
                  else {
                      g.fillOval(b.getXCoor() + 5,b.getYCoor(),
                             b.getParticleSize(),b.getParticleSize());
                      g.fillOval(b.getXCoor() - 5,b.getYCoor(),
                             b.getParticleSize(),b.getParticleSize());
                      g.fillOval(b.getXCoor(),b.getYCoor() + 5,
                             b.getParticleSize(),b.getParticleSize());
                      g.fillOval(b.getXCoor(),b.getYCoor() - 5,
                             b.getParticleSize(),b.getParticleSize());
                  }
             }
```

I confused.
This is the garbled code with the iterator, it is running slow.

```
            itr = particleArr.iterator();
```

```
         super.paintComponent(g);
         while (itr.hasNext()){
             particle=itr.next();
              g.setColor(particle.getColor());
              if (particle.isDead())
                  itr.remove();
              else if (particle.isVanishing())
                  g.fillOval(particle.getXCoor(),particle.getYCoor(),
                        particle.getParticleSize(),particle.getParticleSize());
              else {
                  g.fillOval(particle.getXCoor() + 5,particle.getYCoor(),
                         particle.getParticleSize(),particle.getParticleSize());
                  g.fillOval(particle.getXCoor() - 5,particle.getYCoor(),
                         particle.getParticleSize(),particle.getParticleSize());
                  g.fillOval(particle.getXCoor(),particle.getYCoor() + 5,
                         particle.getParticleSize(),particle.getParticleSize());
                  g.fillOval(particle.getXCoor(),particle.getYCoor() - 5,
                         particle.getParticleSize(),particle.getParticleSize());
              }
```

Comment: +.49 just for the title.

Comment: It strikes me as very wrong to be removing particles from the array in the paint method.  The paint method should just be painting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Collection Alternative - ConcurrentModificationException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/911462/collection-alternative-concurrentmodificationexception)

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html

Comment: I implemented an iterator, however it caused the program to lag moderately.

Comment: @user455497: What do you mean you implemented an iterator? The class of `particleArr`, whatever it is, must have had an iterator to begin with or the foreach loop wouldn't be possible... and the foreach loop uses the iterator, so there shouldn't be any difference unless you're doing something wrong.

Comment: I wasn't clear. I used an ArrayList for the data structure and iterated with java.util.iterator iterator...I'm trying to animate thousands of particles at once and, for whatever reason, the iterator was causing a frame rate dip.

Comment: @user455497: Perhaps it's running slow because it's actually working. Removing an element is roughly a linear time operation on an `ArrayList`. Removing an element from the `Iterator` of a `LinkedList` would be faster (constant time) but operations involving accessing an element by index would be slower.

Comment: Do the Particles have to be in an ordered List? Maybe a SET-Datastructure would increase the speed dramatically.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try getting an Iterator from the array list then calling the remove() method on the iterator to remove the item.

Example

```
Iterator itr = particleArr.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()) {
   Particle b = (Particle)itr.next();
   if (b.isDead())
      itr.remove();
}
```

Edit: Just made the example a bit more relevant to your code.

Comment: +1: If you want to remove elements while iterating, you need to explicitly use an Iterator, rather than the for each syntax which uses one behind the scenes.

Comment: +1, and here is what [the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) says: "The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator methods are fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException."

Answer (score 4):

You can't iterate with an for-each over an Collection AND remove an Element:

```
 if (b.isDead())
    particleArr.remove(b);
```

You may copy your Colletion into another one, first:

```
ArrayList copy = new ArrayList(particleArr);
for (Particle b: copy){
```

Or you can try to Wrap your Collection with an CopyOnWriteArrayList
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html

Or you can use an iterator (This may be the best way):

```
Iterator itr = particleArr.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()) {
   Particle b = (Particle)itr.next();
   if (b.isDead())
      itr.remove();
}
```

edit:
Took the iterator to the options

Comment: While copying would work, it's not really a great solution. Using the `Iterator` is the preferred way to do this.

Comment: +1 since your first sentence hammered my problem right on the head. Pound.

Answer (score 2):

You get an error because you are removing particles from the list inside the for-each loop for the same list. The indexes and length are being changed from within the loop, and Java doesn't know how to handle that. Either loop through the particles a different way, or don't remove them like that