# Java concurrency iterator arraylist shenanigans

Tags: java, concurrency

I have some code that uses an iterator to traverse an arraylist. If a certain condition is met, I want to add an object to the arraylist. Can this be done with an iterator? Or do I need to just use a [l](http://www.loopedyloop.com)oopedy loop?

```
itr=particleArr.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()){
    particle=itr.next();
    if (isMyLifeUtterlyMeaningless)) {
         particleArr.add(new Particle(particle.getXCoor() - 5,
             particle.getYCoor() + 5,
             colorState));
}}
```

which throw a modification exception. So how do I rewrite this with the iterator?

Comment: Is this some kind of homework? THis questions sounds so familiar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097217/the-java-concurrent-modification-exception-debacle-of-2010/4097245#4097245

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
    newParticles = new ArrayList<Particle>();
    for (Particle particle : particleArr) {
        if (isMyLifeUtterlyMeaningless)) {
            newParticles.add(new Particle(particle.getXCoor() - 5,
                                          particle.getYCoor() + 5,
                                          colorState));
        }
    }
    particleArr.addAll(newParticles);
```

Comment: so would it be better practice to do that, or just use a for loop?

Comment: It might be cheaper than doing a lot of array insertions, which are expensive because they require moving elements of the array. If you need to do a lot of insertions/deletions in the middle of a list, and you don't need random access, you should use a LinkedList rather than an ArrayList.

Comment: Personal preference to some extent.  I like this because the intent is clear, and the algorithm is not tied to data structures with random access, so won't behave badly if you change your `ArrayList` to a `LinkedList`.  A `for (int i = 0; i < something; ++i)` loop might be slightly more efficient in the case where you know you are using an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 2):

From the Java API docs:

> [The behavior of an iterator is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified while the iteration is in progress in any way other than by calling [Iterator.remove].](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html)

So it's loopy loop for you.