# Another ConcurrentModificationException question

Tags: iterator, arraylist, concurrentmodification, concurrent-collections

I've searched StackOverflow and there are many ConcurrentModificationException questions. After reading them, I'm still confused. I'm getting a lot of these exceptions. I'm using a "Registry" setup to keep track of Objects:

```
public class Registry {
    public static ArrayList<Messages> messages = new ArrayList<Messages>();
    public static ArrayList<Effect> effects = new ArrayList<Effect>();
    public static ArrayList<Projectile> proj = new ArrayList<Projectile>();

    /** Clears all arrays */
    public static void recycle(){
        messages.clear();
        effects.clear();
        proj.clear();
    }
}
```

I'm adding and removing objects to these lists by accessing the ArrayLists like this: `Registry.effects.add(obj)` and `Registry.effects.remove(obj)`

I managed to get around some errors by using a retry loop:

```
//somewhere in my game..
boolean retry = true;
while (retry){
    try {
        removeEffectsWithSource("CHARGE");
        retry = false;
    }
catch (ConcurrentModificationException c){}
}

private void removeEffectsWithSource(String src) throws ConcurrentModificationException {
    ListIterator<Effect> it = Registry.effects.listIterator();
    while ( it.hasNext() ){
        Effect f = it.next();
        if ( f.Source.equals(src) ) {
            f.unapplyEffects();
            Registry.effects.remove(f);
        }
    }
}
```

But in other cases this is not practical. I keep getting ConcurrentModificationExceptions in my `drawProjectiles()` method, even though it doesn't modify anything. I suppose the culprit is if I touched the screen, which creates a new Projectile object and adds it to Registry.proj while the draw method is still iterating.

I can't very well do a retry loop with the draw method, or it will re-draw some of the objects. So now I'm forced to find a new solution.. Is there a more stable way of accomplishing what I'm doing?

Oh and part 2 of my question: Many people suggest using ListIterators (as I have been using), but I don't understand.. if I call `ListIterator.remove()` does it remove that object from the ArrayList it's iterating through, or just remove it from the Iterator itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Top line, three recommendations:

- Don't do the "wrap an exception in a loop" thing.  Exceptions are for exceptional conditions, not control flow.  ([Effective Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/toc.html) #57 or [Exceptions and Control Flow](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=19) or Example of ["using exceptions for control flow"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259660/example-of-using-exceptions-to-control-flow))
- If you're going to use a Registry object, expose thread-safe *behavioral*, not *accessor* methods on that object and contain the concurrency reasoning within that single class.  Your life will get better.  **No exposing collections in public fields**.  (ew, and why are those fields `static`?)
- To solve the actual concurrency issues, do one of the following:

  1. Use synchronized collections (potential performance hit)
  2. Use concurrent collections (sometimes complicated logic, but probably efficient)
  3. Use snapshots (probably with `synchronized` or a `ReadWriteLock` under the covers)

### Part 1 of your question

You should use a concurrent data structure for the multi-threaded scenario, or use a synchronizer and make a defensive copy.  Probably directly exposing the collections as `public` fields is wrong: your registry should expose thread-safe behavioral accessors to those collections.  For instance, maybe you want a `Registry.safeRemoveEffectBySource(String src)` method.  Keep the threading specifics internal to the registry, which seems to be the "owner" of this aggregate information in your design.

Since you probably don't really need `List` semantics, I suggest replacing these with [`ConcurrentHashMaps`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) wrapped into `Set` using [`Collections.newSetFromMap()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html).

Your `draw()` method could either a) use a `Registry.getEffectsSnapshot()` method that returns a snapshot of the set; or b) use an `Iterable<Effect> Registry.getEffects()` method that returns a safe iterable version (maybe just backed by the `ConcurrentHashMap`, which won't throw `CME` under any circumstances).  I think (b) is preferable here, as long as the draw loop doesn't need to modify the collection.  This provides a very weak synchronization guarantee between the mutator thread(s) and the `draw()` thread, but assuming the `draw()` thread runs often enough, missing an update or something probably isn't a big deal.

### Part 2 of your question

As another answer notes, in the single-thread case, you should just make sure you use the `Iterator.remove()` to remove the item, but again, you should wrap this logic inside the `Registry` class if at all possible.  In some cases, you'll need to lock a collection, iterate over it collecting some aggregate information, and make structural modifications after the iteration completes.  You ask if the `remove()` method just removes it from the `Iterator` or from the backing collection... see the [API contract for `Iterator.remove()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29) which tells you it removes the object from the underlying collection.  Also see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911462/collection-alternative-concurrentmodificationexception).

Comment: Wow, this is a lot of useful information! (And possibly over my head!) I was just checking SO from my cell.. I've got some work to do when I'm back at my comp ;) Just so I understand what you're saying.. you say I should be using private, non-static Collections and access them through methods in the Registry itself? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Snailer:  You got it... I think that's the cleanest approach, given what we know here.  And by "access" the private collections, we mean provide behavioral methods, so `Registry` presents a real data model, rather than just a set of unstructured collections.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly remove an item from a collection while you are still iterating over it, otherwise you will get a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

The solution is, as you hint, to call the `remove` method on the Iterator instead.  This will remove it from the underlying collection as well, but it will do it in such a way that the Iterator knows what's going on and so doesn't throw an exception when it finds the collection has been modified.